# Write a "censor" function in python

Tags: python, string, function

My professor has this function on his slides:

```
def censor(str):
    for ch in "aeiouAEIOU"
        str = str.replace(ch, "*")
    return str
```

Now he asks: *Generalize the censor function so that the letters to be censored are provided as inputs.*

I've tried for a little bit but with bad results. So far the best version is:

```
def censor(str):
    for ch in str:
        str = str.replace(ch, "*")
    return str

str= "WordsToCensor"
```

Then I move to the console and I wrote

```
censor(str)
```

and it will censor it. The problem is that this function returns a fixed numbers of **"*"** regardless of the word's length. Plus, I'm not sure that this was what the professor asked.
Can you help me ?

p.s.: I've looked on past questions but the functions were built in a very different way, I need to code something similar to the code provided by the professor.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: you replaced built-in type `str` with a variable name. Use a different name for the input

Comment: Hint: if the new version takes an input that the old version did not, then it obviously needs to have at least one more parameter than the old version.

Comment: The point is that instead of the function always using hard-coded `"aeiouAEIOU"`, you would instead pass in an additional parameter which is the string containing the letters to censor. So you could call it as follows: `my_output = censor(my_input, "abcxyz")`

Comment: @jarmod I just tried your input but I get the following error: "censor() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: I just deleted the last line of code which was clearly wrong (str="WordToCensor").
Then I started the code and moved on the console wiriting: censor("Word") and I get as a result the censored word. Now the number of " * " matches the lenght of the word. Do you think that I've done this right ?

Comment: If you're struggling with functions, here's a [good introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Os0o3wzS_I).